# Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine error in C# application

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am trying to run MS Access Database in C# application, the database was created in MS Office2007 version, but I have installed MS Office 2010 recently, after that I could not run my application. Any ideas...

Regards,
Raja Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you'll need to use the 2010 provider, which is numbered 14.0

It depends how you have the 12.0 version defined, but it should be as easy as editing the string..

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution...

Please download the exe from the below site and install it.

"https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734"

It works!!!

Regards,
Raja Vignesh